# Using complement to create a DFA with a specific condition

Tags: automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

In my understanding, the complement of an automaton is when the final states become non-final and the non-final states become final.

I tried to apply this method to create an automaton that *never contains a certain substring*. I first tried to create a DFA that *always* contains a certain substring at least once, planning to then give its complement for the opposite property. Let's say the alphabet is **{a, b}** and the substring is **"bab"**.

I started with the regular expression **(a|b)*bab(a|b)*** to create an automaton that contains any word (including no word) before & after the substring **"bab"**, which occurs at least once. However, by this point, I realised a complement would not result in the desired automaton, as the transitions **b->a->b** would still exist regardless, and even so, with a final state in the **(a|b)*** segment of the automaton, the substring **"bab"** is always possible.

I deduced that I misunderstood this method of creating a DFA. In this example, I am looking for a DFA that defines a language with every word *except* words with a given substring, but I would like to know if there is a general method to obtain DFAs with opposite conditions, such as an even number of characters, never having a character appear a certain amount of times, etc. My question is this; how do you create a DFA with certain conditions and then give the complement that results in a DFA *without* those conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the automaton you construct is complete, complementation works just as you described.

Are you sure that the automaton you construct is a DFA, i.e., it is *deterministic*? When you speak about "the transitions **b->a->b**" and a "final state in the **$(a|b)^*$** segment of the automaton" it sound like you have an initial state with a loop for both a and b, then the "transitions **b->a->b**" and a final state with a loop for a and b again. But this is not deterministic: from the start state with **b** you have the option of staying there or going into the **b->a->b** sequence.

A DFA would be one with the transitions:

- $q_0,a\rightarrow q_0,\ \  q_0,b\rightarrow q_b,$
- $q_b,a\rightarrow q_a,\ \   q_b,b\rightarrow q_b,$
- $q_a,a\rightarrow q_0,\ \   q_a,b\rightarrow q_f,$
- $q_f,a\rightarrow q_f,\ \   q_f,b\rightarrow q_f.$

Now you can try the complementation with this one.